# How do I look up the closest value in a 2 dimensional table in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

In Excel 2010, I have set up a two dimensional table that is filled with percent errors. These percentages are calculated based on a user input, so the values change depending on what value the user asks for.

What I would like to do is be able to find the location of the cell in the table that is closest to zero, and return the row and column of that data point for further calculations. Is there a way to do this without using a macro?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: The percent errors are non-negative, and may appear more than once in the table.

Comment: It may be easier to get the further calculations results than to get the address.  What other formulas are going to use this information?  Could you mock up some data and expected outcomes of the other formulas?

Comment: Any further calculations that would be performed would be simple things, like dividing by 1000 or 1000000, or comparing the values to different cells. For reference, I'm creating a worksheet that calculates every series and parallel combination of two resistor values from a given set and determines the most accurate combination, based on what value the user is looking for. So the extra calculations would be purely aesthetic, like displaying megaohms instead of ohms.

Comment: The reason I ask is that finding the value one can use INDEX/MATCH and not the ADDRESS(),OFFSET() or INDIRECT().  The later formulas are all volatile and will recalc every time excel calculates even if the underlying data has not changed.  If all you want is to do math on the value then finding the address is the "Long Way Around" to get to the end result.

Comment: I need to do math on the data in the first row and first column, though. In Row 1 I have a string of 200 resistor values, and in Column A I have those same resistor values. So I need to find the combination of a resistor from Col A and a resistor from Row 1 that will give the lowest percent error. So if the lowest percent error is in F7, I need the values in F1 and A7. Those are the cells that I would be doing the math on.

Comment: Again you can do that by wrapping the formulas for the column and row given by @JohnBustos with INDEX() to get the value directly avoiding the address formula completely.  for example to get the value in Row 1 using his column formula and your data: `INDEX(B1:GS1,IN(IF(ABS(B2:GS201)=SMALL(ABS(B2:GS201),1),COLUMN(B2:GS201)-COLUMN(B2)+1)))` confirmed with Ctrl-Shift Enter.  Then do something similar with the column A and the row formula that he gave.

Comment: Sorry had a typo in the formula `=INDEX(B1:GS1,MIN(IF(ABS(B2:GS201)=SMALL(ABS(B2:GS201),1),COLU‌​MN(B2:GS201)-COLUMN(B2)+1)))`

Comment: @NickU. try my updated answer for your mirrored data.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see what you mean, thanks a lot for your help - I'll keep this in mind while continuing to develop my spreadsheet.

Comment: I came up with something like @JohnBustos 's answer in my Update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be too unreliable for cells with the same absolute value closest to 0 (for example -1 and 1).

This array formula will get the absolute value closest to 0:

```
{ = MIN( ABS( Table1 ) ) }
```

Where `Table1` is the name of the table or range. If the table has values -1 and 1, then it will return 1.

Then those array formulas to get the max row and max column of the values closest to 0

```
{ = MAX(    ROW(Table1) * (ABS(Table1) = MIN(ABS(Table1))) ) }
{ = MAX( COLUMN(Table1) * (ABS(Table1) = MIN(ABS(Table1))) ) }
```

**Update**

This array formula should work for your mirrored data:

```
{ = ADDRESS( MIN( IF( ABS(Table1) = MIN(ABS(Table1)),    ROW(Table1) ) ),
             MAX( IF( ABS(Table1) = MIN(ABS(Table1)), COLUMN(Table1) ) ) ) }
```

You can remove the `ABS` parts if there are no negative values:

```
{ = ADDRESS( MIN( IF(Table1 = MIN(Table1),    ROW(Table1) ) ),
             MAX( IF(Table1 = MIN(Table1), COLUMN(Table1) ) ) ) }
```

The trick is that `Min` and `Max` ignore logical values, so I omitted the third parameter of the `If`

---

**Update 2**

This array formula is a bit simplified version of @JohnBustos 's answer (I am still not sure why he uses `SMALL` instead of `MIN`):

```
{ = MIN( IF(Table1=MIN(Table1), ROW(Table1)*1000 +COLUMN(Table1)) ) }
```

This will return number like `3005` where 3 is the row and 5 is the column, so the address is:

```
{ = ADDRESS( MIN( IF(Table1=MIN(Table1), ROW(Table1)) ),
         MOD(MIN( IF(Table1=MIN(Table1), ROW(Table1)*10^5 +COLUMN(Table1)) ), 10^5) ) }
```

---

The VBA version will be much simpler, because of the `Range.Find` method:

```
Function findMin(r As Range) As Range
    Set findMin = r.Find(WorksheetFunction.Min(r))
End Function
```

with sample uses:

```
=CELL("address", findMin(Table1))
=ROW(findMin(Table1))
=COLUMN(findMin(Table1))
```

Comment: @Slai, you sure this works? I had the issue with my first answer where you stand the chance of returning the Minimum row and the maximum column, BUT what if you have 2+ values being matched in your array. You can get row(val1), col(val2) and, therefore the resulting cell address would end up being neither of those 2...

Comment: @JohnBustos I actually just tested your formula further - it only seems to work when the answer is equal to 0, not if it's close to 0.
Slai, I do find instances like John suggested. I had to test a few more of them to find them.

Comment: @JohnBustos you are right, I tried few more cases and it returns wrong address if the second value is in a column before the first value

Comment: @slai Second update works great so far. If I run into any problems, I'll implement the VBA. I've coded in it before, but I mainly just wanted to see if there was a simpler way to do what I wanted to do - guess not! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to see how others do this, but, for the sake of example, suppose your data was set up in the range `A1:G7`. You could do this via the following array function (meaning press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after entering the formula) as follows:

```
=ADDRESS(MIN(IF(ABS(A1:G7)=SMALL(ABS(A1:G7),1),ROW(A1:G7)),MIN(IF(ABS(A1:G7)=SMALL(ABS(A1:G7),1),COLUMN(A1:G7))))
```

Note that if you wanted the row and column values separately, they are in this formula too:

```
Row: = MIN(IF(ABS(A1:G7)=SMALL(ABS(A1:G7),1),ROW(A1:G7)))
Col: = MIN(IF(ABS(A1:G7)=SMALL(ABS(A1:G7),1),COLUMN(A1:G7)))
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

Given the comment made (which I completely missed) that if the value appeared more than once you could get a different result for the row and column values, I made up a new formula that will give you the result you want.

Give this a try:

```
=CELL("address",INDIRECT(TEXT(SMALL(IF(ABS(B2:GS201)=SMALL(ABS(B2:GS201),1),ROW(B2:GS201)*10^4+COLUMN(B2:GS201)),1), "R0000C0000"),0))
```

Comment: Closest to 0 if there are negative numbers will require ABS().  {-100,-2,5,50} closest to 0 is -2.  The small will return the -100

Comment: I just assumed the percentages would be non-negative, @ScottCraner, but you're 100% right, I'll update the formulas now....

Comment: I made a new table like this in A1:G7, and it works great, but I'm trying to adapt it to my table with the range B2:GS201 (a 200x200 array).

I have the formula (in A1) as this: =ADDRESS(MIN(IF(B2:GS201=SMALL(B2:GS201,1),ROW(B2:GS201)-ROW(B2)+1)),MIN(IF(B2:GS201=SMALL(B2:GS201,1),COLUMN(B2:GS201)-COLUMN(B2)+1)))

But it gives me an incorrect address. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: with the address looking for the actual column and row references you need to remove the `-ROW(A1)+1` and `-COLUMN(A1)+1` as these will make the references relative and return the wrong address.

Comment: Fixed that, but I still get the wrong address. I figured out why - there are two answers. It's giving me the column for one and the row for the other. Is there a fast way of compensating for this? The table will be mirrored across the diagonal - I can always remove one side, it'll just take a bit longer.

Comment: Whew, that one was kind of tough to figure out... I'd still like ot see how others do it, but came up with a new function to do it... Have a look, @NickU.

Comment: Slai's comment below worked out for me - but thanks so much @JohnBustos. I'll try out your method as well. Your comments did teach me a few new tricks for the future!

Comment: @JohnBustos it works! Thanks so much! My first foray into Stack Exchange proved fruitful.

Comment: @NickU., I checked Slai's formula - You sure that one works?? - I think it has the same error my original issue had of possibly returning the non-matched rows and columns.

Comment: @JohnBustos I tested it on three different values, and they all returned the correct result, did you find an instance where it didn't work?